# Error when trying to read json with utf-8 from rest api in Azure data factory v2

Tags: azure, utf-8, azure-data-factory

When I try to preview data in Azure Data Factory (V2) I get the following error:

*Fail to read from REST resource.
The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.
'"utf-8"' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name
Activity ID: 94d11194-b0c2-4302-84ec-0204a45681d4*

I was planning to solve it with maybe Azure Databricks but before I do that I was wondering if it is possible to solve it with Data Factory?

Comment: This means you're calling an external service that returned an invalid content type. [The charset shouldn't be quoted](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index). This page is UTF8 just like 99.9% of web pages. All API responses are UTF8. Azure Databricks can work with APIs.

Comment: If you inspect this page in your browser's Developer Tools you'll see the `Content-Type` header contains `text/html; charset=utf-8` not `text/html; charset="utf-8"`. Something's wrong with the service you call

Comment: Try by adding `Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8` as header.

Comment: @PratikLad does not work. It works fine when I try to read with python code. Not sure if this means that the api has some typo in http request but not with python...

Answer (score 0):

I manged to solve the issue by changing the integration runtime from self-hosted to the default azure (AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime)